# How to navigate to MySQL prompt using cmd without setting environment variable or without navigating MySQL service folder in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run bat file in mysql prompt automatically in all computers without setting environment variable path.

I am using Xampp server,but some of my friends using Wampp and MysqlServer. However I want to run my sql commands by running a .bat file.So I want to navigate to the MySql> prompt first.

I tried following CMD command to find the service,

```
tasklist /svc >mysqld.exe
```

but I can't navigate to mysql>

Help me if someone has any solution. Thanks.

Comment: Run `tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eq mysqld.exe"` you get Mysql service name and after display the details of `sc qc MYSQL57` and to get particular details use `for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %a in ('wmic service where "name='MYSQ
L57'" get pathname /value') do @for /f "delims=" %c in ("%~b") do @echo "%~c"`

Comment: What do you mean by "without setting environment variable?" Do you mean you don't want to permanently change any System or User environment variables?

Could you set an environment variable that only lasts for as long as the script runs (without permanently changing any environment variables)?

Also, is the path to mysqld.exe identical on all the machines you will run the .bat file on?

Finally, when you say you want to "..navigate to the MySql> prompt first," do you mean that you want the batch script to open a MySql prompt, and then execute a command? Could you just pass a command to mysqld?

Comment: I want to find some way to run mysql commands without configuring settings, if mysqld service running on the system. Consider its username root and no password(defult)

Comment: If I can find currently running mysqld service path with cmd command , it will be very useful for this task.

Comment: May be this could solve your problem http://superuser.com/questions/509042/creating-a-bat-file-to-execute-mysql-and-other-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
for /f "tokens=3 skip=3" %a in ('tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eq mysqld.exe"') do @cmd /c sc qc %a ^| findstr PATH
```

Comment: this can find the path, but using this how to  navigate to that path?

Comment: Write the output to a file, read the path using for and do a cd command. Not near a computer now, so can't give a code example.